# Make extraParams in proxy bindable - a solution with 2 overrides

Tags: extjs, proxy, binding, store

extraParams config of a proxy is NOT bindable. The only standard way to bind data to a stores request is via filters. It might seem that extraParams is bindable since the first value is used. It only works one time, any changes to the bound value after that are not registered.
Using remote filters is a solution :

```js
vehicleliststore: {
    model: 'packagename.model.Vehicle',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: Ext.getResourcePath('php/overview/vehicle.php', null, 'packagename'),
        reader: AIIC.Global.defaultProxyReader,
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    filters:[{
        property: 'personid',
        value: '{personId}'
    }],
}
```

This works fine until you want to use the remote filter to realy filter something.
To overcome this problem, make the extraParams bindable by writing 2 overrides. One for the store and one for the ajax proxy. The config loadonextraparamschange is optional.

```js
Ext.define('overrides.data.proxy.Ajax', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',

    mixins :
    {
        observable : 'Ext.mixin.Observable'
    },

    constructor : function(config){
        // do all the constructor stuff of the parent..
        this.callParent(arguments);
        // now do the extended version constructor stuff...
        this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    updateExtraParams : function(newValue, oldValue){
        // when keys change, fire event 'keyupdates'
        //console.log('updateExtraParams');
        this.fireEvent('extraparamsupdated', oldValue, newValue);
    },

});
```

And the override for the store...

```js
Ext.define('overrides.data.Store', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Store',

    mixins :
    {
        observable : 'Ext.mixin.Observable'
    },
    config: {
        loadonextraparamschange : true,
    },

    constructor : function(config){
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.initConfig(config);
        // listen to proxy event 'keyupdated' and then do reload
        me.getProxy().on('extraparamsupdated', this.onExtraParams , me);
    },

    onExtraParams: function(extraParams){
        if( this.getLoadonextraparamschange() )  this.reload();

    }
});
```